# Support .net Core for a nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard-1.6

I have created a nuget package implementing [TinyEncryptionAlgorithm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Menelabs.TinyEncryptionAlgorithm) but it supports only .Net 4.6.1

Now I want to use this nuget into a .net core application NETStandard.Library and I don't know what I have to do.

Do I have to implement a completely new nuget package or I can include both assemplies in the same nuget package?

I have tried to create a NetStandard library and reference it from a .Net 4.6.1 but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple version of .Net you must create portable libs.

Here is a tutorial of how to publish nuget for portable libs.

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015